# Serial date number since "Jan 1, 0000": is this -1 BC or +1 CE?

Tags: matlab, date, time, octave, year0

I was working on dates in Matlab and Octave, and the "serial date number" format is [documented as](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/convert-between-datetime-arrays-numbers-and-strings.html#bth57t1-1)

> A single number equal to the number of days since January 0, 0000 in the proleptic ISO calendar (specifying use of the Gregorian calendar).

In Octave, [they document](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.0/Timing-Utilities.html#XREFdatenum)

> Return the date/time input as a serial day number, with Jan 1, 0000 defined as day 1.

The gregorian calender does not use a [year zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_zero). But Matlab and Octave refer to the year zero. Does this mean that they refer to year -1 BC, as in the [astronomical year numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_year_numbering)?

Days before "October 15, 1582" are "wrong by as much as eleven days", according to the octave manual, which is considerably smaller than a complete year. So I'm trying to sort out this ambiguity.

Comment: `datenum('1-Jan-0001')` gives `367` both [in Octave](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/JbEkNa80V0PdUNcrMU/XwMDAUF3z/38A) and in Matlab. Does that solve the question? (I don't know what CE is)

Comment: @Luis I wasn't sure what year zero means. But it has been resolved below. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, note that the MATLAB and Octave definitions are equivalent

`[MATLAB] N = "number of days since Jan 0, 0000"` ⇔ `[OCTAVE] "Jan 1, 0000 is day 1"`

Since `N = 1` on day 1.

---

The [Wikipedia page on "Year Zero"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_zero) (which you linked to) offers this:

> [...] the year 1 BC is followed by AD 1. However, there is a year zero in astronomical year numbering (where it coincides with the Julian year 1 BC) **and in ISO 8601:2004 (where it coincides with the Gregorian year 1 BC)**, as well as in all Buddhist and Hindu calendars.

MATLAB and Octave appear to have followed the ISO standard, as stated in the [`datetime` docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html):

> datetime arrays represent points in time using the proleptic ISO calendar

**So the year zero, and hence the `datenum` value of 1 days, coincides with the first day of 1BC.**
Per the definitions at the top of this answer

```
"day 1"
= 1/Jan/0000
= datenum(1)
= datetime( 1, 'ConvertFrom', 'datenum' )
= datetime( 0, 0, 1 )
```

---

We can test using `datenum` (number of days) and `datetime` (datetime type object)

```
datenum( 0, 0, 1 ) % = 1, as defined by the docs

datetime( 1, 'ConvertFrom', 'datenum' )     
% = 1/Jan/0000 00:00:00

datetime( 1 + 366, 'ConvertFrom', 'datenum' )
% = 1/Jan/0001 00:00:00
% First day of year 1 after 366 days (leap year 0000 + 1 for Jan 1 )
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed the "and in ISO 8601:2004" part on Wikipedia.

Comment: So when people said that the new millennium didn't start in 2000 but in 2001, I could have replied "it does in the ISO standard that will be written in 4 years!" :D